# Wrong link location with chapter* and pdfbookmark

Tags: hyperref, koma-script, bookmarks

Part of the my chapters in the document with documentclass `scrartcl` should not be listed in the table of contents, but I like to have them in the PDF index. Hence, I used `\pdfbookmark` to get an index entry. Unfortunately, the created link is not placed correctly. It seems like the links goes to the last line of the previous chapter. How can I obtain a correct link?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\Blindtext%

\pdfbookmark{Second Chapter}{2nd}\chapter*{Second Chapter}
\Blindtext%
\Blindtext%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
\setchapterpreamble[o]{\pdfbookmark{Second Chapter}{2nd}}
```

before `\chapter*` to have a bookmark with the anchor just *before* the chapter heading but already on the new page. So, if you select the bookmark, the PDF viewer will jump to the beginning of the chapter heading:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\Blindtext%

\setchapterpreamble[o]{\pdfbookmark{Second Chapter}{2nd}}
\chapter*{Second Chapter}
\Blindtext%
\Blindtext%

\end{document}
```

[image]

See the KOMA-Script manual for more information about `\setchapterpreamble`.

Another suggestion would be to add an explicit `\cleardoublepage` before the `\pdfbookmark` in you example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\Blindtext%

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{Second Chapter}{2nd}
\chapter*{Second Chapter}
\Blindtext%
\Blindtext%

\end{document}
```

Here the anchor is at the top of the text area, so you have some more white-space above the chapter title, if you jump to the bookmark:

[image: bookmark at the top of the text area]

The difference in both suggestions varies depending on the vertical position of the chapter head, e.g., if you would use something like

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-.5\textheight]{chapter}
```

I would use the first suggestion.

Comment: Although the linked position varies a bit with respect to an original chapter, it is exactly what I searched for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Simply move `\pdfbookmark{Second Chapter}{2nd}` behind `\chapter*`.

See the complete code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\Blindtext%

\chapter*{Second Chapter}
\pdfbookmark{Second Chapter}{2nd} % <===================================
\Blindtext%
\Blindtext%

\end{document}
```

and the result after clicking on the second chapter in the bookmark (german "Lesezeichen"):

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: I already tested that and its a bit better, but then the chapter name cannot be directly read. Isn't it possible to align it above the chapter?

Answer (score 0):

you can insert the /pdfbookmark command directly within the definition of a chapter

```
\chapter{\pdfbookmark{chaptername}{chaptername}NAME_OF_CHAPTER}
```

In that case the pdf bookmark points to the first line of the chapter.